# Como substituir o caracter espaço por outro?

Tags: android, edittext, android-styles

O título da pergunta da a entender que é simples eu pergunta tola ,mas não eu gostaria de saber como substituir os espaço de um `EditText` por outra coisa ,como na imagem abaixo:
[image: imagem representando os espaço]

No caso da imagem os espaço são substituídos pelos pontos cinza que está antes das declarações das variáveis JavaScript. Caso copie uma das bolinhas e cole em outro `EditText` ,que não seja esse do editor ,a bolinha se torna um espaço.

Comment: Substituir onde? No editor do Android Studio?

Comment: Não ,eu estou fazendo um editor de código, é nele que quero fazer a substituição.

Comment: Utilize o método [addTextChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)) . Assim você poderá alterar o texto após alterações nele.

Comment: Não dessa forma ,no editor da imagem ,se você copiar uma bolinha da quelas e for em outro editor as bolinha copiada se torna um espaço.

Comment: Coloque o código relevante ao problema na pergunta. De que forma esta a guardar/mostrar o que o código que aparece no editor?

Comment: O foco da questão não tem nada a ver com o código da imagem e sim nôs espaços quê nessa aplicação específica são bolinhas ,mas se copiar uma das bolinhas e e colar em  outra aplicação a bolinha vira um espaço.

Comment: Então qual é especificamente a sua questão ? Como transformar um espaço de uma `String` numa bola ? Qualquer substituição de carateres pode ser feita com [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)). Eu não fui ver mas tem certamente carateres unicode que se assemelham a bolas

Comment: Eu acho que tenho a resposta da pergunta ,não tenho certeza mas acho que pode ser a fonte do editor da imagem.

Comment: Essas "bolinhas" não existem de fato, são somente espaço, o editor exibe assim para facilitar a leitura, por isso ao copiar, só vem espaços

Comment: É uma [configuração](https://imgur.com/a/g8eya) do editor

Comment: Este é um aplicativo Android não de Pc. E eu sei que as bolinhas não existe se não soubesse não teria chegado a conclusão que são espaços.

Comment: Acho que entendi, você quer que apareça assim no editor, e ao copiar, não vá como `.` mas sim espaços. É isso?

Comment: Sim ,o aplicativo do Android que tem essa função se chama Es File Explorer no Note Editor ,nesse editor a tabulação também e mudada mas invés de uma bolinha é uma barra.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de tudo você precisará fazer uma validação. Observe que os pontos cinzas comumente aparecem apenas à esquerda do código, e não à direita ou entre o código. Também precisará trabalhar na formatação visual. Segue uma amostra de como a logica básica funcionará:

```
EditText textBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textBox);
textBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(s.contains(" ")){
            s.replace(" ", ".");
        }
        myOutputBox.setText(s);
    }
});
```